# How can I verify authenticity of (R2-Q5) head/dome

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

This seems to be [553pb003](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=553pb003#T=C&C=11) part. I am trying to find out where the LEGO logo is printed on this 2x2 dome piece given it is the older style dome with the semi-open top stud, meaning there is no LEGO logo on the stud. Does anyone know where should I look for LEGO logo on this piece? If not - is there any way I can verify it as authentic?

[image]

Comment: I think that's why the part design was changed, to add a place to include the logo.

Answer (score 1):

I have part 553pb003 from the sw0213 minifigure (Astromech Droid, R2-Q5) but the one I have has a blocked stud (see photo). I have 2 other astromechs: R7-D4 (sw0119) and R2-Q2 (sw0303) which have similar blocked open studs to yours. There are a lot of markings underneath it on the inside and those include both the Lego(c) sign and part number as well as other numbers. I tried my best to take photos. At least for these markings are evident.

[image: r7-d4 & r2-q2]

[image: R2-Q5 top]